# Can’t bind to ‘ngForOf’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘div’

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular views for displaying object values in a list, I use *ngFor directive to iterate values.
But I faced a strange issue while using this directive which looks like this:

[image]

I break my application to have a multilevel parent and child structure of modules.
In my **app.module.ts** import BrowserModule

[image]

And also I import CommonModule into the child module.

[image]

Comment: Import `ModulesModule` in `AppModule`'s `imports`

Comment: ModulesModule imports  in AppModule but issue is still here

Answer (score 0):

Add the directive (PaginationDirective, is it?) to module's (`ModulesModule`, probably) `declarations` array as well.

Comment: Right now I'm not added any code of pagination in my view.

Comment: Where do you have that *ngFor, then, which generated the error?

Comment: In view I have *ngFor to list item show without paging

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you show the actual template where you are using ngFor

However, the issue may occur if you omit `let` keyword during the `ngFor` call, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="animal of animals">
    {{animal.name}}
</div>
```

Instead you should:

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals">
    {{animal.name}}
</div>
```

Another possible issue could be that you have a tipo like:

```
<div *ngFor="let animal in animals">
```

You should use `of` instead

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals">
```